# Android 13 can't connect to wifi programmatically

Tags: android, wifi, android-13, android-connectivitymanager

I'm trying to connect to a wifi (passing the ssid and password). The callback of the function it does return that the wifi is available, put it does not really connect to the wifi. The code does work in Android 12 and below, but in Android 13 and above is not connecting.

This is the method that I'm using for connecting to the wifi:

```
public void reconnectToWifi(Context context, String password, OnAvailableCallback onAvailableCallback) {
        // Disconnect from the current Wi-Fi network
        wifiManager.disconnect();

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // Create a new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder for the desired Wi-Fi network
            WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .setSsid(ssid)
                    .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                    .build();

            // Create a new NetworkRequest using the specifier
            NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                    .build();

            // Register a NetworkCallback to handle the connection
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network);
                    // Connection successful, perform any necessary actions
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to the Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);

                    boolean connected = isConnectedToSpecificWifi(context, ssid);

                    if (connected) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Really connected to the Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);
                        handler.postDelayed(onAvailableCallback::onAvailableCallback, 5000);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not connected to the Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);
                        reconnectToWifi(context, "pass", onAvailableCallback);
                    }

                    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onUnavailable() {
                    super.onUnavailable();
                    // Connection unsuccessful, handle accordingly
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to the Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);
                    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);

                    reconnectToWifi(context, "pass", onAvailableCallback);
                }
            };

            // Request the network using the NetworkRequest and NetworkCallback
            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);

            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to the Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);
        }
    }
```

I have the permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES">
```